# Crystal Reports vertical alignment in FieldObject

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, .net

I have a WinForms C# application that contains a Crystal Report. In it, I have multiple FieldObjects, whose number of lines vary. I want them to be centred both horizontally and vertically. I can centre them horizontally by setting the HorAlignment property to crHorCenterAlign, but I can't find a way to also set it centred vertically. I haven't managed to find an answer online, so my question is:

**How do you set a FieldObject's text to appear centred vertically**, as you would centre it horizontally using HorAlignment set to crHorCenterAlign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vertical centering, use the horizontal-alignment property.

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to horizontally center a text object (in any mode).  In the past, I've used a formula in place of a text object as a field header.  I try to size the formula (in rotated alignment) to fix the 'worst' case and hope for the best:

```
//insert a CRLF after the first space
Replace({TABLE.FIELD}, " ", " " + Chr(10) + Chr(13), 1, 1)
```

Don't forget, you will also need to swap the values of the height and width properties of the field.